# Why am I getting an error while running a .BAT file?

Tags: batch-file

The code is as follows:

```
@Echo off
Set _File=SQLQuery.txt
Set /a _Lines=0
For /f %j in ('Type %_File%^|Find "" /v /c') Do Set /a _Lines=%j
Echo %_File% has %_Lines% lines.
```

When I run as a .bat file, it gives me error as 'the syntax of the command is incorrect', and when I run all the above commands it runs successfully. Why is this so?

Comment: Use [`%%j`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) (instead of `%j`) from within a batch file.

Comment: Why is it so?  Because you did not read the help file for the `FOR` command as CristiFati has pointed out. **To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead
of %variable.**

Comment: Check out - http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/dip-toes-batch-file-programming-windows/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Echo Off
(Set _File=SQLQuery.txt)
(Set _Lines=)
For /F %%I In ('Find /V /C ""^<"%_File%"') Do (Set _Lines=%%I)
If Defined _Lines Echo(%_File% has %_Lines% line(s).
Pause
```